# Woocommerce show products as list default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm customizing a wordpress theme name SHOPME. I use Woocommerce plugin to control products and display these.

It's OK, but in catalog products page (such as price list), I want it display products as list is default.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cX6F0.png]

I thought that I have to use javascript to click that button after load this page. So I use Chrome dev tool (f12) to code Javascript, this code work on F12:

```
function setListView(){
    var mangClass = document.getElementsByClassName("products-container");
    mangClass[0].classList.replace("view-grid","list_view_products");
}
setListView();
```

I save them as setlistview.js.

```
 function my_scripts() {
     if( is_page( array( 'cua-hang-si','testbanggiasi') ){
       wp_enqueue_script( 'setListView', 'path/setlistview.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    }
    }
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

Then I update function.php to use it in specific page. 
But I got error and cannot use it.  I want when connect to that page, products list show as list view.